# Install sharepoint 2013 in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sharepoint-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to install sharepoint 2013 in Windows Server 2012 R2 ,
what is the best practice methods  i will follow to install successfully
using power shell or without power shell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoSPInstaller](https://autospinstaller.codeplex.com) have as goal to make use of the best practices while installing SharePoint. You won't be disappointed.

Comment: hi , can you share any examples how to use this tool to install sharepoint 2013?